# Указание класса для приведения объекта

Tags: java

Мне необходимо передавать экземпляры разных классов по локальной сети от сервера к клиенту. Для связи клиента с сервером создан отдельный класс, который, по идее, должен принимать от сервера объект в некий стандартный `Object response`, а потом через метод `public Object getResponse()` отдавать результат тому, кто просит, и где объект будет приводиться к нужному типу.

Проблема в том, что при получении объекта от сервера выскакивает `java.io.EOFException`. Насколько я понимаю, невозможно просто принять что-то и хранить до тех пор, пока оно не будет приведено к нужному типу (либо он не может автоматически низвести более сложный объект в просто `Object`).

Отсюда вопрос: нельзя ли как-нибудь указать, во что именно приводить полученный объект?
Выглядеть это, наверно, должно примерно так:

```
Type t = object1; // указывается класс, к которому приводится входящий объект
objin = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
response = (t)objin.readObject();
```

**Обновление**

Попробовал следующее:

```
response = anyClass.cast(objin.readObject());
```

где `anyClass` - класс, заданный непосредственно перед получением ответа (берётся из заготовленного для ответа объекта через `answer.getClass()`). Не получилось - всё равно показывает `java.io.EOFException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любой объект в Java может быть приведен к Object. Так как даже если вы его не наследуетесь от Object явно, компилятор сделает это за вас.
Ваша проблема с EOFException явно не из-за неверного приведения типов.

Answer (score 0):

Вы какую-то ерунду пишите. Объект, прочитанный через `ObjectInputStream.readObject` - уже прочитан, и от того, что вы его куда-то приведете, он более прочитанным не станет. Ищите проблему в другом месте.

PS Из того, что я увидел: вы делаете `new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream())` для чтения каждого объекта - или один раз на соединение? Если первое, то не удивительно, что ничего не работает. Ни `ObjectInputStream`, ни `getInputStream` не предназначены для разовой работы.

Comment: `new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream())` делается один раз на соединение. Как указал zzashpaupat, ошибку стоило искать немного в другом месте. Но всё равно спасибо.